# Changing permissions for ntp

Tags: ntp

Recently my raspberry pi stopped updating the time when it was turned off/rebooting. I tried changing to time zone with `raspi-config` to reset the time, but this did not work.

I tried checking the status of ntp with `systemctl status ntp` and I was told

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/init.d $ systemctl status ntp

● ntp.service

   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)

   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I tried installing ntp again with `apt-get install ntp` but I was told it's already installed.

I tried to restart the service with `etc/init.d/ntp restart` but I am told that permission is denied. I tried to change the permissions of ntp with `chown pi /etc/init.d/ntp` but this did not work.

I tried to access ntp with root, using `sudo su` but I am still told permission is denied, even after `chown root /etc/init.d/ntp`.

How can I get ntp working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make ntp executable.

```
sudo chmod +X /etc/init.d/ntp
```

Then after a quick reboot everything was back to normal.